# Cannot connect Windows Azure from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, server-explorer

Hi I tried to connect a Windows Azure website from VS2013 server explorer. I got this message saying I need to install latest version of Azure SDK but I already have the latest version. Even when I downloaded the latest version of SDK, I couldn't install it again as I already have it. Anyone else having this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also install the Windows Azure SDK for .NET?  The one in your attachment is for Visual Studio integration not the actual SDK.

Here is a screenshot from Web Platform Installer: [image]

Comment: I sorted out the problem .. i don't know how. I uninstalled and reinstall from Web Platform Installer again and it fixed. Maybe you are right. But I can't find two things on WPI though. I think I just reinstalled the same thing. I am not sure. Thanks your answer led me to fix it :)